# Soluto installation fails with "Check your internet connection or firewall settings"

Tags: windows-7, installation, firewall, soluto

A few days ago, I wanted to install [Soluto](https://www.soluto.com/). The installation failed with this error message:

> Check your internet connection or firewall settings!

Because everything was fine with my connection, I went to the Control Panel and disabled Windows Firewall. I tried again with the same results.

I remember that this happened a few months ago with the Chrome installer, but I don't remember  if/how I fixed it.

What could be wrong and how do I fix it?